# Delete all elements of a certain tag / copy all elements of a certain tag /

Tags: html, tags

this is my first post, so please bear with me if its not understandable.

I've got a problem with a html doc. It is a very long doc that contains h2 and p elements. Only the text between the h2 tags is relevant for me.
Is there a way to either remove all the p tags and their content or copy all h2 tags and their content to a new document?

I couldn't find anything for this topic on the internet, this is why I started a new thread.

Thanks so much for your help!!
Best Spickert

Answer (score 0):

Select `<h2>` with mouse,
click `CTRL + shift+ L`
then `ALT + shift + arrow right`

- if you are using VScode